# Web-scraping based on a div id using Rstudio

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I am trying to web-scrape government data from a website. However, the website has no table class and the contents appear as div id. The URL of the website is:

https://nreganarep.nic.in/netnrega/all_lvl_details_dashboard_new.aspx?Fin_Year=2023-2024&Digest=WJEEpOm1k0Ptz2KJJGSoqA

I am attaching a photo of the page.
[image]

The code that I have tried knowing it is incorrect:

```
url = "https://nreganarep.nic.in/netnrega/all_lvl_details_dashboard_new.aspx?Fin_Year=2023-2024&Digest=WJEEpOm1k0Ptz2KJJGSoqA"
url_read = read_html(url)
url_ex = url_read %>% html_element(".someTable")

url_ex = url_read %>% html_element("cotainer")
url_ex = url_read %>% html_element("cotainer")
```

Comment: Eric I know this sounds strange but I can help you with the problem, but "give me recommendations for x" questions are not allowed on StackOverflow

Comment: the bad news w.r.t. your question is that you're looking at Javascript (try blocking Javascript in your browser, nothing will show up on the page now). It also doesn't appear that the site is referencing JSON data, it all appears to be done on the server side. So you will probably have to use RSelenium

Comment: @Mark I removed the part not allowed. I tried using RSelenium: ```rs_driver_object = rsDriver(browser = 'chrome', chromever = '115.0.5790.171', verbose = FALSE)```. It returns an error that versions do not match with the ones available. I tried to downgrade the error and got the error: Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 14415 after 2226 ms: Connection refused
Check server log for further details

Comment: Eric RSelenium, despite it being what you need, is kinda a pain to set up, at least in my experience. I would work off of a tutorial to get it set up

Answer (score 0):

Table is in *iframe*  which is sourced from `national_dashboard_detail.aspx`, without providing any parameters it seems to return results for all states without any issues:

```r
library(rvest)

"https://nreganarep.nic.in/netnrega/national_dashboard_detail.aspx" %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_element("table.table") %>% 
  html_table()
#> # A tibble: 46 × 7
#>    National                National National National National National National
#>    <chr>                   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
#>  1 1.Total No. of Distric… 739      739      739      739      739      739     
#>  2 2.Total No. of Blocks   7,172    7,172    7,172    7,172    7,172    7,172   
#>  3 3.Total No. of GPs      2,69,650 2,69,650 2,69,650 2,69,650 2,69,650 2,69,650
#>  4 I             Job Card  I      … I      … I      … I      … I      … I      …
#>  5 4.Total No. of Job Car… 14.88    14.88    14.88    14.88    14.88    14.88   
#>  6 5.Total No. of Workers… 26.31    26.31    26.31    26.31    26.31    26.31   
#>  7 6.Total No. of Active … 9.74     9.74     9.74     9.74     9.74     9.74    
#>  8 7.Total No. of Active … 14.43    14.43    14.43    14.43    14.43    14.43   
#>  9 8.(i)SC worker against… 19.75    19.75    19.75    19.75    19.75    19.75   
#> 10 9.(ii)ST worker agains… 16.24    16.24    16.24    16.24    16.24    16.24   
#> # ℹ 36 more rows
```

For filtering, you could pick correct values from the form source or from request list of browser's dev tools, e.g. for
*State : GOA District : NORTH GOA Block : SATARI Panchayat : MAUXI*
, this should work:

```
https://nreganarep.nic.in/netnrega/all_lvl_details_new.aspx?panchayat_code=1001005054&block_code=1001005&district_code=1001&state_code=10&page=p&fin_year=2023-2024&Digest=123
```

Only `*_code` parameters seem to make a difference; `Digest` is bit odd, skipping it will trigger some kind of "URL Tampered" event, yet any random value seems to work.

Or you could approach this through `rvest` sessions by filling and submitting a search form and extracting the updated iframe source URL.

For Goa it looks something like this:

```r
# open session
dashboard_url <- "https://nreganarep.nic.in/netnrega/all_lvl_details_dashboard_new.aspx"
s <- session(dashboard_url)

# form options for ddl_state:
s %>% html_elements("#ddl_state option") %>% print(max_n = 10)
#> {xml_nodeset (35)}
#>  [1] <option selected value="ALL">ALL</option>\n
#>  [2] <option value="02">ANDHRA PRADESH</option>\n
#>  [3] <option value="03">ARUNACHAL PRADESH</option>\n
#>  [4] <option value="04">ASSAM</option>\n
#>  [5] <option value="05">BIHAR</option>\n
#>  [6] <option value="33">CHHATTISGARH</option>\n
#>  [7] <option value="10">GOA</option>\n
#>  [8] <option value="11">GUJARAT</option>\n
#>  [9] <option value="12">HARYANA</option>\n
#> [10] <option value="13">HIMACHAL PRADESH</option>\n
#> ...

s %>% 
  # extract (1st) from
  html_form() %>% 
  getElement(1) %>% 
  # set ddl_state to "10" (value for Goa)
  html_form_set(ddl_state = "10") %>% 
  # submit form
  session_submit(s, form = .) %>% 
  # iframe src location is now updated with parameters, 
  # extract it and prepend with https://nreganarep.nic.in/netnrega/
  html_element("iframe") %>% 
  html_attr("src") %>% 
  # fetch page inside same rvest session, extract and parse table
  paste(dirname(dashboard_url), ., sep = "/") %>% 
  session_jump_to(x = s, url = .) %>% 
  html_element("table.table") %>% 
  html_table()
```

Resulting table for Goa (*ddl_state 10*):

```r
#> # A tibble: 45 × 7
#>    `State    : GOA`           `State    : GOA` `State    : GOA` `State    : GOA`
#>    <chr>                      <chr>            <chr>            <chr>           
#>  1 Total No. of Districts     2                2                2               
#>  2 Total No. of Blocks        12               12               12              
#>  3 Total No. of GPs           191              191              191             
#>  4 I             Job Card     I             J… I             J… I             J…
#>  5 Total No. of JobCards iss… 0.39             0.39             0.39            
#>  6 Total No. of Workers[In L… 0.51             0.51             0.51            
#>  7 Total No. of Active Job C… 0.07             0.07             0.07            
#>  8 Total No. of Active Worke… 0.08             0.08             0.08            
#>  9 (i)SC worker against acti… 2.49             2.49             2.49            
#> 10 (ii)ST worker against act… 42.65            42.65            42.65           
#> # ℹ 35 more rows
#> # ℹ 3 more variables: `State    : GOA` <chr>, `State    : GOA` <chr>,
#> #   `As on 09-08-2023` <chr>
```

Detailed filtering can get bit tricky with this as options for each dropdown are only delivered once the selection in the previous one is submitted. In other words, you'd have to go through 4 form submissions if you want to pick a value for each filter from a list of valid options.

<sup>Created on 2023-08-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for this, one question: is an automatic process for this? For example, I need to extract all the district, block, and Panchayat data for the state of Tamil Nadu. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Short answer is yes - You can absolutely do this :)  Though providing a complete crawler is out of scope for this question. Feel free to split provided dplyr pipeline into as many pieces as you need to better fit the logic into loops and conditionals. As noted in the answer, one has to go through a form submission before getting valid values for next filtering parameter, so you'd basically have to traverse a tree of all  District-Block-Panchayat branches just to get valid parameter values.

Comment: There's also a good chance that numeric code values make more sense to someone with some local knowledge (iTAMIL NADU = 29; ARIYALUR = 2931; ..) so table URLs for can be constructed without requesting all form variants.

Comment: Sorry, just a few more clarifications. How do you find the numeric codes of district and district? I tried using the web developer tool but could not find anything. Plus if I put State, district, block, and panchayat names can be included and how will they be included in the code. Will it be put here ```html_form_set(ddl_state = "10")```

Comment: To get District options, State must be selected. In browser you just select the State and new request is triggered by javascript and District options can be inspected. In rvest you have to set the `ddl_state` form field and submit the form, from the response (i.e from updated session) you should get valid options with  `select#ddl_dist option` CSS selector.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvEhR.png .  You should only need to change form fields that have changed, i.e you first go though `html_form_set(ddl_state = "29") %>% session_submit(s, form = .)` to get a list of districts for TAMIL NADU.

Comment: Then `html_form_set(ddl_dist = "2931") %>% session_submit(s, form = .)`  to select the first district and so on with Block & Panchayat. But if you know valid values, setting those in one go should work as well, like `html_form_set(ddl_state = "29", ddl_dist = "2931")`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a `RSelenium` appraoch:

```r
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)
library(magrittr)

pjs <- wdman::phantomjs(verbose = FALSE)
rD <-   rsDriver(browser = "phantomjs", verbose = FALSE)
cl <- rD[["client"]]

url <- "https://nreganarep.nic.in/netnrega/all_lvl_details_dashboard_new.aspx?Fin_Year=2023-2024&Digest=WJEEpOm1k0Ptz2KJJGSoqA"
cl$navigate(url)

## 1. find iframe
ifr <- cl$findElements("css selector", "iframe")

## 2. Switch to iframe
cl$switchToFrame(ifr[[1]])

## 3. Find table
tab <- cl$getPageSource()

tab[[1]] %>% 
   read_html() %>% 
   html_elements("table") %>% 
   extract2(2L) %>% 
   html_table()

# # A tibble: 46 × 7
#    National                                  National         Natio…¹ Natio…² # Natio…³ Natio…⁴ Natio…⁵
#    <chr>                                     <chr>            <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
#  1 1.Total No. of Districts                  739              739     739     739     739     739    
#  2 2.Total No. of Blocks                     7,172            7,172   7,172   7,172   7,172   7,172  
#  3 3.Total No. of GPs                        2,69,650         2,69,6… 2,69,6… 2,69,6… 2,69,6… 2,69,6…
#  4 I             Job Card                    I             J… I     … I     … I     … I     … I     …
#  5 4.Total No. of Job Cards issued[In Cr]    14.88            14.88   14.88   14.88   14.88   14.88  
#  6 5.Total No. of Workers[In Cr]             26.31            26.31   26.31   26.31   26.31   26.31  
#  7 6.Total No. of Active Job Cards[In Cr]    9.74             9.74    9.74    9.74    9.74    9.74   
#  8 7.Total No. of Active Workers[In Cr]      14.43            14.43   14.43   14.43   14.43   14.43  
#  9 8.(i)SC worker against active workers[%]  19.75            19.75   19.75   19.75   19.75   19.75  
# 10 9.(ii)ST worker against active workers[%] 16.24            16.24   16.24   16.24   16.24   16.24  
# # … with 36 more rows, and abbreviated variable names ¹​National, ²​National, ³​National, ⁴​National,
# #   ⁵​National
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

cl$close()
```